# Android onResume not called after finish() command on different activity

Tags: java, android, onresume, onpause

I have 2 Activities. My first activity calls the second activity. Once a button is clicked in the second activity it calls the finish() method on that activity causing it to return to Activity 1. This is fine, but my problem is that when it returns none of the expected methods are called (onResume(), onRestart(), on Start()). Is there anything that I could be missing? Anything that can inhibit the call? I have logs in each of the methods making sure that they aren't called. I have also added the android:noHistory="false" into my manifest to try solving the problem, but it did not fix it.

Here is the way I call the Activity

```
intent = new Intent(this, ViewEdit.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is an example of the setup of the log in the methods

```
public void onStart(Bundle bundle){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(MYACT, "On Start");
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If there was `onStop` in the activity there will be `onStart` when you come back to it. There is no way to disable that.

Comment: If the onStart, or any of the other methods were activating I would be fine with that, but my problem is that none of the methods are activating after I call the finish(); in my second Activity.

Comment: You should add onPause() and onStop() to verify with logCat that it is calling them first.  If they are not called, your 1st activity was never paused to begin with.  Though, at least onPause() should have been called.